# Loading image shows after a long delay when clicking a button to call jquery ajax

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to show a loading image on a button click that will validate a form via ajax, but the loading image shows only after some delay (when uploaded to server it takes more than 2 seconds to show the image). But I want it in the moment of button click event. My code is given below.

```
$("#Save").click(function() {
    // shows theloading image (here I am expecting the loading image, it never shows.)
    $("#load_img").show();  
    // calls ajax for vaidation
    lookUpValidation($("#item1")) 
    // calls ajax for vaidation
    lookUpValidation($("#item2"))
})
function lookUpValidation(this_element,id) {
    url = "/validate/lookupid/"+id,
    lookUpValidationResult  = false;
    lookUpValidationData    = false;    
    if(this_element.val()!="") {
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type : "POST",
            async : false,
            data : {    
                "value"   : this_element.val()
            },      
            beforeSend : function(data) {
                // shows theloading image
                $("#load_img").show();
            },
            complete : function(data) {             
                if(data) {
                    var res = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
                    lookUpValidationData = res;
                        if(res.field) {    
                            lookUpValidationResult = 1;
                        }
                        else
                            // not found
                            lookUpValidationResult = 2;

                    }
                    else {
                        // not found
                        lookUpValidationResult = 2;
                    }       
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            // null
            lookUpValidationResult = 3;
        }
        return lookUpValidationResult;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="k-loading-image" id="load_img" style="display:none;">
    <div class="k-loading-color">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: from your code it looks like it should show right away

Comment: Yes, I don't know why it is not showing there ...

Comment: html is <div class="k-loading-image" id="load_img" style="display:none;"><div class="k-loading-color"></div></div>

Comment: Is the image is of large size? Try  with alert `$("#Save").click(function() {
    alert('test');
    $("#load_img").show();

})`.

Answer (score 0):

The call to the server is done synchronously, so the click handler blocks the browser from showing the image.

To my knowledge there is no cross-browser way to force and ui update from javascript. But you may have some luck with implemting a custom solution for this. A google search should assist in this.

Another way to handle this would be to prevent the default handling of the click event, and to submit the form after all async validation has succeeded.

The better solution IMHO is to validate each field asynchronously while the user is filling in the form and only enable the save button when all validation has been completed. This can be done using `.blur()` so that each input is validated when the user moves to the next one. Validation while the user is typing could be implemented by a combination of `.keypress()` and `setTimeout()`. Here is a short example illustrating this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <form id="form" action="form.html">
        <label for="item1">Validate email on blur:</label><input id="item1" type="text"/><span id="item1-status">Invalid</span><br/>
        <lavel for="item2">Validate email while writing</lavel><input id="item2" type="text"/><span id="item2-status">Invalid</span><br/>
        <button id="Save" type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var validState = {
            "set": function (name, state) {
                this[name] = state;
                updateUI();
            },
            "item1": null,
            "item2": null
        }

        function formIsValid() {
            var res = true;
            for(var name in validState) {
                res = res && validState[name];
            }

            return res;
        }

        function validString(val) {
            return val==null ? ""
                : val ? "Valid" : "Invalid"
        }

        function updateUI() {
            $("#item1-status").text( validString(validState.item1) );
            $("#item2-status").text( validString(validState.item2) );
            $("#Save").prop("disabled", !formIsValid());
        }

        function isEmail(str) {
            return /\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i.test(str);
        }

        function validateItem1() {
            validState.set("item1", isEmail($("#item1").val()));
        }
        function validateItem2() {
            validState.set("item2", isEmail($("#item2").val()));
        }

        // Validate after loosing focus
        $("#item1").blur(validateItem1);

        // Use timeout to validate when user has stopped typing
        $("#item2").blur(function() {
            var handle = $(this).data("validation-timer");
            if( handle ) clearTimeout(handle);
            validateItem2();
        }).keydown(function () {
            var self = $(this);
            var handle = self.data("validation-timer");
            if( handle ) clearTimeout(handle);
            var new_handle = setTimeout(validateItem2, 1000);
            self.data("validation-timer", new_handle);
        });

        updateUI();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How doesn't the validation work? Does something else happen after the click handler?

Comment: yes depending on the validation result I am setting an error message array for showing the errors. If I made it async form is submitted without showing the error messages.

Comment: If you put a `return false` in your click handler you can use `$('#theForm').submit()` when validation is passed. This way you can use asynchronous validation

Comment: Thank you for your reply I will try this and update you the result. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Load that image already in your page with something like:

```
body {
   background: #fff url(path/to/load_image.gif?) no-repeat -1000px -1000px;
}
```

BTW, you could validate all the items, process them and return an ok response (using json headers to avoid th parseJSON) to redirect with just one call.